# Constructing compact-open topology via closure operator

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

Suppose $X$, $Y$ are topological spaces, with the additional assumption(maybe not necessary) that $X$ is Hausdorff and $Y$ is metrizable. The *compact-open* topology on the space $C(X,Y)$ of continuous maps from $X$ to $Y$ is usually defined as the topology generated by the subbasis $V(K,U):=\{f\in C(X,Y):f(K)\subset U\}$, where $K$ is compact in $X$ and $U$ is open in $Y$. To have a better grasp of the concept, I tried to deduce the same topology via the definition of compact convergence. That is, a sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $C(X,Y)$ converges compactly to $f\in C(X,Y)$ iff. for any compact set $K\subset X$, $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ in $K$. **Of course, it's easy to check that this is exactly the same type of convergence as it is in compact-open topology**. However, I want to put things another way.

With the definition of compact convergence in hand, we may easily define a corresponding closure operator $\operatorname{cl}:\mathcal P(C(X, Y))\to\mathcal P(C(X, Y))$. We need to verify that the operator $\operatorname{cl}$ satisfies Kuratowski's Axioms, which we list as below:

> (1) $\operatorname{cl}(\emptyset)=\emptyset$.
>   (2) $\operatorname{cl}(A)\supset A$.
>   (3) $\operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{cl}(A))=\operatorname{cl}(A)$.
>   (4) $\operatorname{cl}(A\cup B)=\operatorname{cl}(A)\cup\operatorname{cl}(B)$.

(1)(2)(4) is trivial, the only problem is (3). Let's restate (3) as the following:

> Let $A$ be a subset of $C(X,Y)$. Suppose for each $n\in\mathbb N$, the sequence $\{f_{n,i}\}_{i=1}^\infty$ with $f_{n,i}\in A$ converges compactly to $f_n$. Moreover, suppose $f_n$ converges compactly to $f$. Then there exists a sequence $\{g_n\}$ in $A$ such that $g_n$ converges compactly to $f$.

Apparently this proposition can be proved directly, but I'm having a difficult time with it. For the case where $X$ admits a compact exhaustion, I feel comfortable to prove the result. But for more general cases, I don't know where to start. I tried to take some specific sequence, such as the diagonal, but it didn't seem to work. Is there a direct proof for this? Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman I'm sorry if there is any confusion.  I think I defined it implicitly in mentioning “With the definition of convergence...”. More precisely, the closure operator is defined as “$f\in \operatorname{cl}(A)$ iff. there is a sequence in $A$ that converges compactly to $f$”. Also in the second quoted block there is a restatement independent of the previous notation.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman It was a typo :( I'm so sorry. Thanks for pointing out. Is the definition clear now? To rephrase what I said in the previous comment, the closure of $A$ is the set of limit points of $A$, and a limit point $f$ of $A$ is defined as the limit of a compactly convergent sequence, i.e., we call $f$ a limit point of $A$ iff. there is a sequence $f_n$ in $A$ that converges compactly to $f$.